# Sharepoint2007: How to delete a survey question which has a blank title?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, survey

A new survey question was accidently added which has a blank title.

It appears in the list of questions but without a link to get into the editor.

How to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Although the list of questions did not display a link to edit the empty question, there is actually a link in the source. I just showed the source code, copied out the link, pasted it into the browser address. It worked.